# Virtual Machines

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I have 3 VMs and I need to know weather they reside on one physical host or not, and if they not, I need to clone them to one physical host using OpenStack features.

I am not sure how they were created because they were created by my prof. I have these informations:

```
Linux version 3.2.0-45-virtual (buildd@panlong) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #70-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:31:52 UTC 2013
```

The VMs are:

- 10.242.144.92
- 10.242.144.89
- 10.242.144.90

Can you help with any idea?